Personal Polygon RPC: heimdall & bor not syncing after starting from snapshot
I need personal RPC, because of volume of requests, so I decided to host it on one of my servers. Installed and configured heimdall as two services: heimdalld and heimdall-rest (for the REST API). Then also bor. Snapshots provided by stakepool - https://docs.stakepool.dev.br/polygon/snapshots/polygon-mainnet-pruned Age is good - from 20th of October, 2024. All good, but...
When I start heimdall it looks like it is way behind the current height.
...
INFO [2024-10-26|16:56:59.054] Committed state                              module=state height=20944461 txs=0 appHash=0B349559D847B65A1E9772A80DB0F01B9CACA45844631EA62054F0C984DA6D07
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:05.299] Unable to fetch block by number from child chain block=null err="Post \"http://localhost:8545\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8545: connect: connection refused"
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:05.300] Error validating milestone                   module=Milestone startBlock=63519900 endBlock=63519911 hash=0x06e3181117a9d1262fd181b44e5b776b0e76739553ef6a7f6ff71482a887eea0 milestoneId="8998a528-e436-4132-adfe-ca1d8e509fb6 - 0x4e5b776b0e76739553ef6a7f6ff71482a887eea0" error="End block number with confirmation is not available in the Bor chainEndBlock63519911Confirmation16"
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:05.300] Hash is not valid                            module=Milestone startBlock=63519900 endBlock=63519911 hash=0x06e3181117a9d1262fd181b44e5b776b0e76739553ef6a7f6ff71482a887eea0 milestoneId="8998a528-e436-4132-adfe-ca1d8e509fb6 - 0x4e5b776b0e76739553ef6a7f6ff71482a887eea0"
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:05.301] Executed block                               module=state height=20944462 validTxs=1 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:05.322] Committed state                              module=state height=20944462 txs=1 appHash=7C0A3B05C5CE8D5B5F71DC2007CAE144EB0D6226E1F290E1320C3F4ABB4D7AAA
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:11.652] Unable to fetch block by number from child chain block=null err="Post \"http://localhost:8545\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8545: connect: connection refused"
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:11.652] Error validating checkpoint                  module=checkpoint startBlock=63518630 endBlock=63519397 rootHash=0x3afa01de031aa72c31c40fa29f8209914d7199e7fc1ecd53ef24b5ee3cacd3c8 error="blocks not found locally"
ERROR[2024-10-26|16:57:11.652] RootHash is not valid                        module=checkpoint startBlock=63518630 endBlock=63519397 rootHash=0x3afa01de031aa72c31c40fa29f8209914d7199e7fc1ecd53ef24b5ee3cacd3c8
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:11.654] Executed block                               module=state height=20944463 validTxs=1 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:11.669] Committed state                              module=state height=20944463 txs=1 appHash=2CA280A2D3B71AA223755324C42BC0DE3C2A682C8BDA88C903766CB4398441F5
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:17.886] Executed block                               module=state height=20944464 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:17.903] Committed state                              module=state height=20944464 txs=0 appHash=74724D4B71F8C16A849A1AC4DBDF9C1E948FFB6764916B586A5ECBF9811890EE
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:24.135] Executed block                               module=state height=20944465 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:24.162] Committed state                              module=state height=20944465 txs=0 appHash=F5891AED62C2CC6C3F427DB955380D42210D9371A3CDA7525838E889A582DC15
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:31.401] Executed block                               module=state height=20944466 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:31.421] Committed state                              module=state height=20944466 txs=0 appHash=F5891AED62C2CC6C3F427DB955380D42210D9371A3CDA7525838E889A582DC15
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:37.626] Executed block                               module=state height=20944467 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:37.640] Committed state                              module=state height=20944467 txs=0 appHash=F5891AED62C2CC6C3F427DB955380D42210D9371A3CDA7525838E889A582DC15
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:44.782] Executed block                               module=state height=20944468 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:44.802] Committed state                              module=state height=20944468 txs=0 appHash=F5891AED62C2CC6C3F427DB955380D42210D9371A3CDA7525838E889A582DC15
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:51.176] Executed block                               module=state height=20944469 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
INFO [2024-10-26|16:57:51.195] Committed state                              module=state height=20944469 txs=0 appHash=F5891AED62C2CC6C3F427DB955380D42210D9371A3CDA7525838E889A582DC15
...

So, heimdall is way behind in order to expose valid checkpoints and milestones to bor. Not to mention heimdall can't find peers, seeds I found don't work, so I can't get to sync and start bor. What bor outputs:
...
WARN [10-26|17:01:54.759] Failed to fetch latest no-ack milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
INFO [10-26|17:01:55.778] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=4
WARN [10-26|17:01:56.759] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:01:56.759] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1
WARN [10-26|17:01:58.758] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 400"
INFO [10-26|17:01:58.758] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=1
INFO [10-26|17:01:59.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=127
INFO [10-26|17:01:59.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=127
WARN [10-26|17:02:00.758] Failed to fetch latest no-ack milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
WARN [10-26|17:02:00.776] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=5   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:00.776] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=5
WARN [10-26|17:02:02.760] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:02.760] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1
INFO [10-26|17:02:03.761] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=2
INFO [10-26|17:02:04.293] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=128
INFO [10-26|17:02:04.293] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=128
INFO [10-26|17:02:05.776] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=6
WARN [10-26|17:02:06.759] Failed to fetch latest no-ack milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
WARN [10-26|17:02:08.759] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:08.759] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1
INFO [10-26|17:02:08.760] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=3
INFO [10-26|17:02:09.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=129
INFO [10-26|17:02:09.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=129
WARN [10-26|17:02:10.773] Failed to fetch latest milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
WARN [10-26|17:02:10.775] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:10.775] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=1
WARN [10-26|17:02:12.757] Failed to fetch latest no-ack milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
INFO [10-26|17:02:13.761] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=4
WARN [10-26|17:02:14.293] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=130 error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:14.293] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=130
WARN [10-26|17:02:14.294] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=130 error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:14.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=130
WARN [10-26|17:02:14.760] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 500"
INFO [10-26|17:02:14.760] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/lastNoAck attempt=1
INFO [10-26|17:02:15.777] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/milestone/latest    attempt=2
WARN [10-26|17:02:18.759] Failed to fetch latest no-ack milestone, please check the heimdall endpoint and status of your heimdall node err="context deadline exceeded"
WARN [10-26|17:02:18.760] an error while trying fetching from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=5   error="error while fetching data from Heimdall: response code 400"
INFO [10-26|17:02:18.760] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=/checkpoints/latest  attempt=5
INFO [10-26|17:02:19.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=131
INFO [10-26|17:02:19.294] Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1           attempt=131
...

So, of course my heimdall-rest (API service) outputs
...
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:53.472] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=GET url=/bor/span/1 status=500 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:55368
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:53.472] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=GET url=/bor/span/1 status=500 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:55366
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:53.531] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=POST url=/ status=404 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:53096
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:53.531] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=GET url=/milestone/lastNoAck status=500 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:55378
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:54.105] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=POST url=/ status=404 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:53096
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:54.105] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=GET url=/milestone/latest status=500 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:55390
INFO [2024-10-26|06:27:58.472] Served RPC HTTP response                     module=rest-server method=POST url=/ status=404 duration=0 remoteAddr=127.0.0.1:39296
...

Any ideas how to get my heimdall to sync, so the other two services could work and I finally can use my RPC for my purposes? Thank you!
